# Can't change LESS highlighting colors in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less, syntax-highlighting

**Problem:** I'm using VS2012 Dark theme and I can't read LESS syntax with standard colors, so I wanted to change them, but when I go `tools` -> `options...` -> `environment` -> `fonts and colors` -> `Text editor` in the list I can't see LESS options.

**Steps:**

1. Installed VS2012
2. Web Essentials 2012
3. Visual studio SP 1
4. ASP.NET Web Tools 2012.2
5. Restart PC

I did this like 6 - 7 times already and never had such a problem. Do I need to re-install whole visual studio?

### Solution

Installed Visual studio 2012 color and theme editor extension, and LESS options appeared.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't see the LESS options but after installing that extension, they appeared and all is good in the world :)